# Ordinal logistic hierarchical regression model in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, hierarchical-data, ordinal, multilevel-analysis

I am currently trying to estimate a ordinal logistic regression model with hierarchical data in R (my dependent variable has three categories and the data stems from the 50 U.S. states; I just need random intercepts, no random slopes, but I also have a cross-level interaction). In Stata I would use the "meologit" command but I can't find an equivalent in R. Is there a command that allows me to calculate such a model?
I have already read about clmm and clmm2 in the ordinal package and about mixor but as far as I understood there is no multilevel-option for those. Alternatively, I have tried lmer but I don't think I can specify that I want to calculate an ordinal logistic regression model there.

Does anyone have any advice for me?

Thank you very much and have a nice week,
R.Van

Comment: I assume you already saw this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238581/how-to-use-ordinal-logistic-regression-with-random-effects If you don't mind going bayesian are a few good examples like https://data.princeton.edu/pop510/pop510slides11.pdf or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225963/multilevel-ordered-logistic-regression-in-stan or (not ordinal but quite useful) https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/tutorial_rstanarm.html
You can prepare the cross-level interaction when constructing the design matrix. Let me know if it is of any help

Comment: Dear Jon, Thanks for your reply! I already saw the other post but clmm and clmm2 don't work with my version of R (even though I have the latest version). Mixor does work but I already calculated my model in Stata with the meologit command and mixor in R gives me vastly different results (I want to use R to produce a better graph than in Stata; but out of my 5 interaction terms only one is statistically significant in Stata, while with mixor in R all five of them are highly significant...). I don't have any experience with Bayesian models but I might follow your suggestion and try it! Thanks